# Big Oh Classification

Tags: big-o

Say that I have a function that has the following growth:

```
2000n^2 + log n
```

Is it possible for me to conclude that the function is part of the set of functions that fall into the category of `O(n)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(some function) is the limiting behavior of a function.

Does there exist some C such that C*n describes the upper limit of the function you described for all n?

If you look closely at your function, you can set C to 2000 such that 2000*n^2 = C*n^2...which is greater than C*n.

So no, it is not O(n).

Answer (score 0):

No since O(log n) < O(n^x) for any fixed x, O(2000n^2 + log(n)) = O(n^2)

An easier way to see this is that since O(log n) < O(n^x), O(log n) < O(n^2) and so O(2000n^2 + log(n)) <= O(2000n^2 + n^2) = O(2001n^2) = O(n^2) and since O(2000n^2 + log(n)) has an n^2 term, it is at least as big as n^2 giving us O(2000n^2 + log(n)) >= O(n^2). Now we have that O(2000n^2 + log(n)) <= O(n^2) and O(2000n^2 + log(n)) >= O(n^2)  so we can conclude that O(2000n^2 + log(n)) = O(n^2)